# Q learning state actions pair, what is 'state' exactly?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, conv-neural-network, dqn

Hello all I'm trying to write a deep q learning network, I am not using any sort of gym environment or anything, just a cnn using screen grab.
since i'm not using gyms nicely coded user friendly environments. what do I actually save for my 'state'
is it simply the image the network got as input? I have action and reward coded no problem but for the state, action, reward, next state. I'm uncertain of what it is I use for 'state' is it just raw pixel data, or convoluted image? will this work? Any help is greatly appreciated. Hope I got the point across,
I'm needing to save state, action, reward and next state in a replay memory to give back to the net, I'm just unsure of what state is if youre not using open ai gym.

Comment: If you don't have a gym environment, what is your agent trying to do? What is it trying to learn? or are you just doing image classification? What are your actions and reward? The state is just a single configuration of the environment.

Comment: Its trying to play a game on my computer, I have coded the actions I could take if I where playing the game using the key pad. so it has 4 actions possible, up, down, left, right. then for reward im just using the score of the game. Its a legit game though its intended to be played by people not code. so would I just use the exact pixel array that I feed into the network for that iteration as the state? I feel like that's a massive amount of information.

Comment: Your state would be too complicated with raw pixels. In reality you'd use convolution to extract features. They often stitch 4 frames together and convolute it down. I would follow a tutorial if I were you. https://medium.com/ml-everything/learning-from-pixels-and-deep-q-networks-with-keras-20c5f3a78a0

Comment: If you have code I can take a look but the link above should show you how to do it

Comment: If you don't mind I would love if you'd take a look, I'm new to stack overflow how do I pm you? or can you pm me ill send you what I got so far

Comment: I don't think you can pm on here. Perhaps make a github account and repo for the code and give me the link and we can talk on there. Make a private repo then only people you want to see it can.